# Use 1.0 TB volume device owned by root, how to add files and folders?

Tags: command-line, permissions, hard-drive, 22.04, filesystem

I have a formatted (was windows) 2 TB SSD with Ubuntu 22.04 installed.  No Windows on this drive.  There was a formatted 1 TB drive on the PC when Ubuntu was installed.  No windows on this drive. I don't want to use Windows on this Ubuntu PC. The 1 TB drive is owned by root, so I, normal user, can't add folders or files. No other users will ever be added to this PC. What is the recommended way to make the 1 TB drive (listed in Other Locations) a device I can add folders and files to?  No error messages during install or use of Ubuntu.Both drives are one partition.

Answer (score 1):

> The 1 TB drive is owned by root, so I, normal user, can't add folders
> or files. No other users will ever be added to this PC. What is the
> recommended way to make the 1 TB drive (listed in Other Locations) a
> device I can add folders and files to?

Assuming the filesystem on the 1TB drive's partition is a Unix/Linux filesystem that supports Unix/Linux type permissions ...

Mount it with like:

```
mkdir ~/my_mnt
```

then:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdyx ~/my_mnt
```

changing `sdyx` to the actual partition name on the 1TB drive e.g. `sdb1`.

That is if it’s not already mounted, or otherwise use its current mount-point instead of `~/my_mnt` below.

Then change the ownership of the mount-point(*while the partition/block device is mounted*) to the `user:group` of your choice like so:

```
sudo chown user:group ~/my_mnt
```

or to your current logged-in `user:primary_group` like so:

```
sudo chown "$(id -un):$(id -gn)" ~/my_mnt
```

This will permanently change the ownership of the top-level(*AKA root*) directory of the mounted filesystem at `~/my_mnt` i.e. the filesystem on the 1TB drive's mounted partition to the supplied `user:group` giving them full permissions to create directories/files under it.

**Notice:**

This is the normal situation for data storage disks/partitions like e.g. external USB disks, when you format them to a Unix/Linux filesystem, the invoking user i.e. your user becomes the owner of that filesystem’s top-level directory and it’s even the normal behavior for non-Unix/Linux filesystems when you mount them their top-level directory becomes owned by the invoking user as well AKA user-space virtual filesystem mounts.

Comment: Why should a specific user be the owner? Shouldn't the root own it, with other users having read/write permissions?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OP says there are no other users "*No other users will ever be added to this PC*" ... Also, the top-level directory i.e. `/` on the target filesystem is just a directory ... And changing ownership in this case IMO is the shortest "user friendly" solution and the most secure one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Also "*Shouldn't the root own it*"? ... No, the reason it's already owned by `root` is, as the OP mentioned, Ubuntu was previously installed on it which is understandable and necessary, but now that it's used as an additional user storage disk, it doesn't realy need to be owned by `root` or follow the previously set directory permissions hierarchy but rather needs to be secure data-wise.